# How to implement a custom delegate that is in a static class?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I want to write a generic method that allows me to use a pattern of test methods that returns a boolean with the result and outputs a string message:

```
public delegate bool TestMethodDelegate<string, bool>(out string message);
```

I use it in a static class (and it is declared in that class):

```
public static void ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(TestDelegate<string, bool> aTestMethod)
{
    // do repeated stuff before
    string message;
    bool result = aTestMethod(out message);
    // do repeated stuff after
}
```

Now I want to call this method from multiple places in the code but can't get it right... tried several options, like:

```
string message;
CommonTests.ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(() => return IsAppInstalled(out message));
```

Needless to say, this doesn't compile... any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate can contain type parameters, but what you have is invalid - you can't specify as you have, it should be declared:

```
public delegate bool TestMethodDelegate(out string message);
```

To execute:

```
CommonTests.ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(IsAppInstalled);
```

If you want the message output and return result from this static method, you'd have to change the signature of the static method:

```
public static bool ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(TestMethodDelegate method, out string message)
{
    // do repeated stuff before
    bool result = method(out message);
    // do repeated stuff after

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the generic parameters from your delegate:

```
public delegate bool TestMethodDelegate(out string message);
```

and

```
public static void ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(TestMethodDelegate aTestMethod) { .. }
```

Comment: This answer is uncomplete. You answered the first part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It ins't allowed to write:

```
public delegate bool TestMethodDelegate<string, bool>(out string message);
```

Because you're trying to declare a generic delegate by using `string` and `bool` as a type. So what about:

```
public delegate bool TestMethodDelegate<T>(out T message);
```

And:

```
public static void ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(TestDelegate<string> aTestMethod)
{
   string message;
   bool result = aTestMethod(out message);
}
```

So you can do:

```
CommonTests.ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(IsAppInstalled);
```

But as you can see you can't use `message` here. So a very simple solution could be:

```
public static void ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(TestMethodDelegate<string> aTestMethod, out string aParameter){
    bool result = aTestMethod(out aParameter);
}
```

And then:

```
string message;
CommonTests.ExecuteTestMethodDelegate(IsAppInstalled, out message);
```